# compare function for anagram program

Tags: c

hey guys i have this code here but i cannot understand what the cmpfunc function does actually i don't understand the return statement can someone explain it to me ? than

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int values[] = { 88, 56, 100, 2, 25 };

int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
{
   return ( *(int*)a - *(int*)b );
}

int main()
{
   int n;

   printf("Before sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

   qsort(values, 5, sizeof(int), cmpfunc);

   printf("\nAfter sorting the list is: \n");
   for( n = 0 ; n < 5; n++ ) {
      printf("%d ", values[n]);
   }

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)). Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Your program works well. You want to read a good book on C programming to understand `cmpfunc` and you probably should use the debugger and put a breakpoint in it. We don't have time to teach you all of C.

Comment: What it actually does is throwing type-safety out the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with a `qsort` description - [here it is.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/)

```
void qsort (void* base, size_t num, size_t size,
            int (*compar)(const void*,const void*));
```

So you need to write a function with such inputs and output to use in `qsort`.

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b)
```

is ok, but inputs are `*void` and you need to compare integers in your case. So you will need to convert types. That's why there are

```
 *(int*)a
```

Finally, return values of `cmpfunc` must match requirements from `qsort` description.
In article I mentioned at the begging of this post you can find this implementation:

```
int compareMyType (const void * a, const void * b)
{
  if ( *(MyType*)a <  *(MyType*)b ) return -1;
  if ( *(MyType*)a == *(MyType*)b ) return 0;
  if ( *(MyType*)a >  *(MyType*)b ) return 1;
}
```

Your version is just a proper simplification of it.

Comment: actually it is not my version it's a version i found on the web and i am trying to understand !! than again for taking the time to explain :)

Answer (score 1):

`cmpfnc` is comparing the values of of pointers provided. It uses `void*` so that any kind of data can be passed to it and compared after being converted. First it converts the `void*` values to `int*` and then deferences them via `*` to subtract the integers they are *pointing* at

Answer (score 0):

When you want to sort an array of some kind you need a comparison function.
the comparison function is used by qsort in order to compare two objects in the array. In this case the compare function compares two integers.

Comment: The OP gives the `cmpfunc` and it is in C (with arrays and `qsort`) not in C++ (with vectors and `std::sort`)!